# How do I prevent the numbers from being replaced with a percentage?

Tags: excel

This seems like it's an obvious answer, but I still need help.
My little girl climbed on my lap and started pounding the keyboard today. I don't know what she hit, but when I started entering numbers into my Excel docs after that, it replaces them with the percentage equivalent (4 is replaced with .04, 120 would become 1.2, etc.).

It's a program setting, as every doc I edit or any doc I create new behaves this way. I've checked in the Excel preferences, tried formatting the cells involved, and have spent my entire work day trying to fix this, as I can't enter any new information now without it being automatically converted to the new number.

It's not a viewing thing either, as any documents I create and send to someone else to view show the converted number, not the original one I entered. The people can enter the correct numbers on their own computers, and I can see the correct numbers, but if I enter anything, it is automatically converted. The only fix so far seems to be selecting 'text' for the cell format, which is not fixing the problem.

Please, please, please help!

Comment: Once this is resolved, please consider having her visit [Sign up to continue to  Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=votedialog&returnUrl=%2Fquestions%2F32513957%2Fhow-do-i-prevent-the-numbers-from-being-replaced-with-a-percentage).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the settings under 
`[File][Options][Advanced]`

Ensure

`[] Automatically insert a decimal point` is disabled (unchecked)
 and

`[`✓`] Enable automatic percent entry` is enabled (checked)`